# How do I convert a for loop into a while loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am practicing on how to do a for/while loop but I can't seem to understand how to get a for loop to a while loop.

Here is the for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < buttonsDefault.buttons.length; i++) {
    $('body').append("<button>" + buttonsDefault.buttons[i] + "</button>")  
}
```

How would I make it a while loop?

```
while (buttonsDefault.buttons.length > i) {
    $('body').append("<button>" + buttonsDefault.buttons[i] + "</button></div>")    
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you cannot convert a `for` into a `while` loop you should get back to how a `for` loop works first.

Comment: You need to increment your counter i within your while. In a for loop the last part does exactly that. Also don't forget about initializing your counter (that is taken care of in the first part of the for loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manage the increments of `i` yourself in this `while` loop. When you do that, it will look a lot like the `for` loop:

```
let i = 0;  // start at 0
while(i < buttonsDefault.buttons.length) { // while it's in range
    $('body').append("<button>" + buttonsDefault.buttons[i] + "</button>") 
    i++ // increment
}
```

If you look at the structure of the `while` loop, you'll see the similarity to the structure of the first line of a `for` loop and hopefully understand why people prefer to use `for` in situation like this.

Of course, as you move on in javascript, you'll find that there are a lot of other ways to loop through arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pop` aswell to make it even shorter:

In case `buttonsDefault.buttons` is an **array**:

```
while( button = buttonsDefault.buttons.pop() ) {
    $('body').append("<button>" + button + "</button>") 
}
```

Or make an array out of `buttonsDefault.buttons` in case its a jQuery **collection**:

```
var buttons = [...buttonsDefault.buttons]; // spread
while( button = buttons.pop() ) {
    $('body').append("<button>" + button + "</button>") 
}
```